# Configuring an Site to Site VPN ,open VPN client on Pfsense and Azure will host Open VPN Scess Server

Tags: openvpn, site-to-site-vpn, azure-networking

Dears,

I am relatively  new  to Open vpn , by reading through forums i have tried may of the suggestions, but still not able to get it work. I am trying to have a Site To Site VPN , with Open VPn Access Server on Azure. Site A and Site B will have open VPN client configured on  pfsense. **Windows machines on the Site A and Site B are able to ping the Open VPN Access Server Internal Ip (10.0.0.4), But  Windows machines on Site A LAN is not able to reach the Site B LAN desktop and vice versa.** 
Please find the below configuration i have added.

**Vm on Azure (open VPN Access Server)**
OS: ubuntu 
**Added Routes on virtual network:**

**Address Prefix:** 192.168.50.0/24 , NEXT Hop: 10.0.0.4
Open VPN Access Server Installed with Below Settings
Internal IP :10.0.0.4
VPN Client Subnet: 192.168.59.0/24
VPN Mode: Layer 3 (routing/NAT)
Should VPN Clients Have Acess to private Subnets:
Yes, using routing rounting (Advanced)
Private subnets to whcihc clients should be given access:
10.0.0.4/24
Server Config Directives
push "route 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 192.168.40.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 192.168.50.0 255.255.255.0"
route 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0
route 192.168.40.0 255.255.255.0
route 192.168.50.0 255.255.255.0
client-to-client
User Permissions:

**Site A user:**
Authentication :Local
Configure VPN Gateway:Yes
Allow Client to act as a VPN gateway for this client side  subnets:
192.168.10.0/24
Site B user:
Authentication :Local
Configure VPN Gateway:Yes
Allow Client to act as a VPN gateway for this client side  subnets:
192.168.50.0/24

**Open VPN Client on PFSense**
Router: PFSense
Open VPN Client Config

Site A Internal Ip :192.168.10.0/24
Tunnel Network:192.168.59.0/24
Remote Network:192.168.50.0/24,10.0.0.0/24
Custom Options:
route 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0

Site B Internal Ip :192.168.50.0/24
Tunnel Network:192.168.59.0/24
Remote Network:192.168.10.0/24,10.0.0.0/24
Custom Options:
route 192.168.50.0 255.255.255.0

**Lan Interface Rules on both firewall.**
Default Allow LAN T0 any rules , Gateway is Open VPN Client Interface

Added Outbound rules on both Site A and Site B (SiteB Lan ip will be 192.168.50.0/24)
Interface : OPEN-VPN Interface Address , Source :127.0.0.1/8 ,port:*, Destination :*,Port: 500(ISAKMP) NAT Address :OPEN-VPN Interface Address

Interface : OPEN-VPN Interface Address , Source :127.0.0.1/8 ,port:*, Destination :*,Port: * ,NAT Address :OPEN-VPN Interface Address

Interface : OPEN-VPN Interface Address , Source :192.168.10.0/24,port:*, Destination :*,Port: 500(ISAKMP) NAT Address :OPEN-VPN Interface Address

Interface : OPEN-VPN Interface Address ,  Source :192.168.10.0/24,port:*, Destination :*,Port: * ,NAT Address :OPEN-VPN Interface Address

Comment: Machine on Site B is Able to Acess the Desktop on Site A, we need to add the route on client Custom options in Pfsense open vpn client, example

Answer (score -1):

Machine on Site B is Able to Acess the Desktop on Site A, we need to add the route on client Custom options in Pfsense open vpn client, example Route 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0 10.0.0.4

Comment: But i am trying to connect a SIP phone (3CX) from Site B  to Avaya IP Office V2 on Site A, this don't seem to connect , don't know if Avaya Ip Office needs some additional configuration for it